# What order are signals sent to a process group in Linux?

Tags: linux

If I ctrl-c a program at the terminal, Linux will send a SIGTERM to all members of the process group.  Is the order each process recieves the signal well defined?

Eg: if I have a process tree something like this (<-- denotes [parent] <-- [child])

```
[PID 2] <-- [PID 3] <-- [PID 4]
                     \_ [PID 5]
                      |_[PID 6]
```

Will pids 4,5,6 receive the signal first, sending a SIGCHLD To pid 3?  And then pid 3 and pid 2?

Comment: I may be wrong but I believe that the parent gets the signal and then sends it to the children so that they shutdown. Or the parent takes care of shutting down any child processes.

Comment: The signal's definitely sent to all the members of the process group, which by default will include any fork()-ed children.  The parent needs to wait() on the children to avoid creating zombies, but I can't find any documentation on whether children are signal-ed before or after the parent.

Comment: It occurs to me that, for my application, it probably doesn't matter, since my children are out of my control, they can do a setpgrp or change sessions, so I'll have to re-issue the signal anyways to be safe.  Still, it'd be interesting to know the answer.

Comment: It couldn't hurt to post a question to http://www.linuxquestions.org/ .

Comment: I don't think it really matters what order the signals are sent, since they will just sit in the process' pending queue until the process gets scheduled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been browsing the Linux kernel source and I think I have the answer.  When sending a signal via kill, Linux iterates over the linked list held in the pid structure, which contains all the tasks that use that PID.  I *believe* that this means it iterates over processes in a group in the *reverse* order they were forked() as the PID is added to the linked list with hlist_add_head_rcu, which inserts it at the head.  I don't think this behavior should be relied on though, as they could change it in several ways.